# Newbie TikZ question : A line starting inside a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a line from (p) to (x0), but I want that the 
line starts inside the node (p) and not at the border. I tried
using "xshift" but it doesn't work.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex', thick, overlay]
    \path[->]<1-> node[cell, label=left:\texttt{x}] at (-1,0) (x0) {};
    \path[->]<1-> node[cell, label=left:\texttt{p}] at (-3,2) (p) {};
    \path[->,red,xshift=-5mm]<1-> (p) edge [bend left] (x0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try (p.center) in place of (p).

Comment: Also setting `inner sep=0` will make the border be tighter around the text.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that comments and Gonzalo's answer are correct but I want to add more informations.
First the good and natural way it's to use `(node.center)` if you want to draw something from the center of a node.

`outer sep` is used to placed the anchors (except center anchor) so it's damage to modify `outer sep`. Below I place a picture to explain how to use the different options.

[image]

Now in your case, there are some remarks to add. First , you use `edge` but if you use `to`and if you want to get the center of the final node, you can find another way.
The first picture shows the normal way. `outer sep` with `line width` are determined to get the start and the end of the edge near the shape of the node. The interesting case is the third one, because `edge` is a special operation (see the pgfmnual) and in the edge is drawn before the last node and the arrow goes to (2,-1).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{spath}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw](A) {A};
\node[circle,draw](B) at (2,-1){B}; 
\draw[->,red,thick] (A) edge [bend left] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw](A) {A};
\node[circle,draw](B) at (2,-1){B}; 
\draw[->,red,thick] (A.center) edge [bend left] (B.center);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw](A) {A};
\draw[->,red,thick] (A) edge [bend left]   node[at end,circle,draw,black,thin]{B}(2,-1) ;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw](A) {A};
\node[circle,draw](B) at (2,-1){B}; 
\draw[->,red,thick] (A.center) to [bend left] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Je suis toujours impressionné par la qualité et les détails de vos réponses

Comment: Merci ! :) mais cela dépend beaucoup du sujet traité !

Answer (score 9):

There are several options here. You can set `inner sep` to `0pt` and use `p.center` instead of `p` (as suggested in the comments), or you can use the `shorten <=` option to shorten the start of the line by the given distance. A little example illustrating those approaches (I removed some of your settings since you didn't provide the appropriate definitions in your code snippet):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex', thick, overlay]
  \path[->] node[label=left:\texttt{x}] at (-1,0) (x0) {};
  \path[->] node[label=left:\texttt{p}] at (-3,2) (p) {};    
  \path[->,red] (p) edge [bend left] (x0);

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
  \path[->] node[label=left:\texttt{x}] at (-1,0) (x0) {};
  \path[->] node[inner sep=0pt,label=left:\texttt{p}] at (-3,2) (p) {};    
  \path[->,red] (p.center) edge [bend left] (x0);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
  \path[->] node[label=left:\texttt{x}] at (-1,0) (x0) {};
  \path[->] node[label=left:\texttt{p}] at (-3,2) (p) {};    
  \path[->,red,shorten <= -5pt] (p) edge [bend left] (x0);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
  \path[->] node[label=left:\texttt{x}] at (-1,0) (x0) {};
  \path[->] node[label=left:\texttt{p}] at (-3,2) (p) {};    
  \path[->,red,shorten <= -10pt] (p) edge [bend left] (x0);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's also a `shorten >=` option to shorten the end of the line by the given distance.